# How to design an application - passing application option values to custom functions

Tags: c#, oop

I'm building a C# Windows Forms application that will load music files from given directory, do some operations with these and save them.

I have a custom class with music specific methods (functions). I have created it's instance in main form class to call these methods with given arguments. The methods not only need data to work with (i.e. filepath) but sometimes they also need to load some values from application options (i.e. which music file extensions the application should load from given directory). What's the best approach to load those options?

Should I just create an instance of options class in the main form class and pass the whole instance to every function(method) I call? Or should I store the options class instance in my custom music class?

Main Class:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    private MusicFunctions mf = new MusicFunctions();
    public mainForm()
    {...}

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...
      mf.loadMusicFiles(path, true);
      // btw what's the best approach to load data into form objects (i.e. DataGridView)? Should I pass those as arguments to my functions or create a new object in my custom function and return it as a function return value?
    }

    private void optionsChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I would have to create functions inside musicFunction class to be able to change options
        int a = 10;
        mf.ChangeOptions(a);
        ...
    }

}
```

MusicFunctions Class

```
public class MusicFunctions
{
    private MyOptions options;
    public class MusicFunctions()
    {
        options = new Options();
    }

    public void loadMusicFiles(string filepath, bool includeSubfolders = false)
    {
      foreach (string ext in options.Extensions)
      {
           ....
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither. You might want to get acquainted with the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scope of those options. If those options are read only once and have to do with the program, the class instance should be held by the application (or you could store the options in a .config file and use the Framework classes to read them in that case). If the options have to do with a music, the instance of the class representing that song should hold it.

Also check the suggestion of @EliAlgranti in the comments in your question.